# Collection types supported by Spring - Map VS Props

Tags: java, spring, collections

I just came through this question,

Which of the following collection types are supported by `Spring` while creating a Bean currently?

`list`, `set`, and `props` i am aware of.

How about **map**, **tree** ..??

Also how can i choose between `Props` and `Map` usage..??

Comment: Supported where? Configuration, data binding in the web, creating as bean? More context is needed for an answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum updated, it's bean creation,

Comment: `Props` is a `map`

Comment: @Lino when to use `map` or `Props`

Comment: My blog post here might be useful https://jstobigdata.com/spring/mapping-and-injecting-collections-in-spring/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @vinS and @ShivamSingh, you can use all four collections List, Set, Map, and Properties. For your second question, `prop` tag value can/should contain only string values, however, `map` values can contain values of any type. So for `map` values, you can store other collections also.

You can only use Strings as properties (and keys). For anything else use plain Map instance. [Some reference](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/55849-referencing-collections-props)

As mentioned in the reference above, you can see the difference in the use of `map` and `prop` tags,

```
<props>
    <prop key="foo">blahhhh</prop>
    <prop key="bar">arrrrgh</prop>
</props>

<map>
    <entry key="foo" value="blahhhh"/>
    <entry key="bar">
        <bean class="java.lang.String">
            <constructor-arg value="arrrrgh"/>
        </bean>
    </entry>

    <!-- and you can even do -->
    <entry key="baz" value-ref="someBean"/>
</map>
```

Answer (score 2):

Spring supports 4 collection type.

```
List, Set, Map, and Properties
```

[Here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-collections-list-set-map-and-properties-example/) are some example to use them.

Answer (score 1):

`Spring` supports below 4 major collection types :

1. List
2. Set
3. Map
4. Properties

I assume question is about *Inject values in collections*.